# Column name of the table as a variable in Kohana3 framework

Tags: php, mysql, insert, kohana

I have such a code in the Kohana3 framework, that saves values in the Days table.

```
$column_names=array('morning','day','evening','night');
$values=array('abc','xyz','eeeee','ooooo');

$result=ORM::factory('Day');
$result->morning=$values[0];
$result->day=$values[1];
$result->evening=$values[2];
$result->night=$values[3];
$result->save();
```

How can I use $column_names to write something like, i.e. using variable as a column name:

```
$result->$column_names[3]=$values[3];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parentheses to wrap your array in.

```
$result->{$column_names[3]} = $values[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

[array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is what you need:

```
$values = array_combine($column_names, $values); 
$result->values($values);
$result->save();
```